# i am getting error while installing ros indigo in ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

bash: source/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash: No such file or directory
I am getting this problem. And the path is also correct. And I installed all the things thrice but still the same problem. while I am able to open gedit .bashrc. can somebody help.....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234644/i-am-getting-error-while-installing-ros-indigo-in-ubuntu-14.04-lts?/) by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the error is `bash: source/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash: No such file or directory` you simply missed a space when editing your `.bashrc`

The line should be

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

and not

```
source/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

---

**EDIT**

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Find all lines containing `source/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` and delete.
Add then following line:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

you are good to go.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2016-05-19**:
mig i also tried with space but the same problem is occurring can u write the whole thing after echo command i am not getting that right......waiting for ur answer

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-19**:
open your `.bashrc` with an editor, you still have the line before in it.
Remove all lines sourcing something from ROS and only add the last one.

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2016-05-19**:
can u plz write the command not understanding a bit mig sry to disturb u

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2016-05-19**:
nw i am getting bash: /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash: Permission denied so should i keep only one line and delete all the other lines.....

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2016-05-19**:
thnks mig problem soolved....